# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"report"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a report#show view which I would to link_to, but I'm unsure about how to set up the routing.

In my packages#show view:

```
<% link_to 'Report', package_report_path(@package) %>
```

Here's my `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :packages do
    resources :sales, only: [:new]
    resources :report, only: [:show]
  end

  root "packages#index"

end
```

If I do `rake routes`:

```
  package_report GET    /packages/:package_id/report/:id(.:format) report#show
```

Answer (score 0):

The route is set up correct, but you need to pass both `@package` and `@report` to the package_report_path, like:

```
<% link_to 'Report', package_report_path(@package, @report) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `report` resource is nested under the `package` resource. So, you have to pass both `@package` and `@report` to the `package_report_path` helper method:

```
<% link_to 'Report', package_report_path(@package, @report) %>
```

Comment: Similar result: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"report", :id=>nil, :package_id=>"14"} missing required keys: [:id], I'm not even sure if I need a report to have the ID.

Comment: Yes, because you need to make sure `@report` is present and its not `nil`

Comment: You need to grab the `report` you want to show in your `@report` instance variable and then my answer will work for you.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry I'm very new

Comment: For example, you can do: `@report = @package.reports.first` or `@report = @package.reports.find(params[:report_id])`. something like this. I can help more if you show your corresponding  controller's action.